# Escape additional characters with Django autoescape

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I'm trying to extend Django default `autoescape` behavior to escape the `{}` characters.

The issue is our Django templates are printing inline JS templates (angular.js). But this means some variable django prints might contains `{{}}` characters that are going to be executed - thus allowing XSS.

We're usually doing escapes and backend validation, but some old pages might've skipped the basic checks. Any chance we can hook directly in the autoescape behavior to also HTMl encode those extra characters automatically?

Comment: If you are rendering JavaScript from user content you are basically asking for trouble. Create JSON in pure Python to get user data into Angular.

Comment: @KlausD. obviously, but that's a legacy system. I don't have the resource to migrate the whole thing. I'm just trying to lower the risks for the time being.